# Не работают вектора C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Я работаю над 2D игрой на SFMl c++. но думаю это не принципиально.

есть класс World. В нем есть вектор типа строка(это матрица мира), и есть двумерный вектор типа sf::Sprite(из SFML).

из символов я преобразую в sf::Sprite т.е. текстуры

ВНИМАНИЕ! Ошибка не в SFML а в векторе(вроде бы)

вообщем вот код:
World.h:

```
#ifndef WORLD_H
#define WORLD_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef unsigned short int _usi;

class World : public sf::Transformable, public sf::Drawable
{
public:
    World();
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
    void generateWorld();

private:
    sf::Texture textureTile;

    //level one
    const _usi worldLevelOneHeight = 10;
    const _usi worldLevelOneWidth = 20;
    std::vector<std::string> worldLevelOne;
    std::vector<std::vector<sf::Sprite>> worldSpriteLevelOne;
};

#endif // WORLD_H
```

World.cpp:

```
#include "world.h"
#include <iostream>
World::World()
{
    textureTile.loadFromFile("media/Tiles.png");
}

void World::generateWorld()
{
    std::cout<<"test1\n";
    worldLevelOne.push_back("                    ");
    worldLevelOne.push_back("                    ");
    worldLevelOne.push_back("                    ");
    worldLevelOne.push_back("                    ");
    worldLevelOne.push_back("                    ");
    worldLevelOne.push_back("                    ");
    worldLevelOne.push_back("====================");
    worldLevelOne.push_back("                    ");
    worldLevelOne.push_back("                    ");
    worldLevelOne.push_back("                    ");
    worldLevelOne.push_back("                    ");
    std::cout<<"test1\n";
    for(_usi h = 0; h < worldLevelOneHeight; ++h)
    {
        for(_usi w = 0; w < worldLevelOneWidth; ++w)
        {
            worldSpriteLevelOne[h].push_back(sf::Sprite());
            //set textures
            if(worldLevelOne[h][w] != ' ')
            {
                worldSpriteLevelOne[h][w].setTexture(textureTile); //ошибка вродебы вот тут
                if(worldLevelOne[h][w] == '=') worldSpriteLevelOne[h][w].setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0,0,73,73));
                else  worldSpriteLevelOne[h][w].setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(73,0,73,73));
                worldSpriteLevelOne[h][w].setPosition(w*73, h*73);
            }
        }
    }
}

void World::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    states.transform *= getTransform();
    for(_usi h = 0; h < worldLevelOneHeight; ++h)
    {
        for(_usi w = 0; w < worldLevelOneWidth; ++w)
        {
            target.draw(worldSpriteLevelOne[h][w], states);
        }
    }
}
```

в коде я указал возможную строку из-за которой происходит ошибка

ВНИМАНИЕ! ошибка не сборки, а выполнения!

Comment: [mcve] бы... Запустить не сможем это, а кода не так и мало.

Comment: вроде исправил.

Comment: Какая именно ошибка? Вы уверены, что `worldSpriteLevelOne` не пустой, и что вы не выходите за его границы?

Comment: да, я уверен на сотку. Я эту задачу решал с помощью динимического массива и все работало( перешел на вектор по причине: "утечки памяти, а при очищении программа крашилась:)")

Comment: Доступ за границу массива вызывает неопределенное поведение: программа может делать что угодно, в том числе **не** крашиться. Отсутствие краша вообще ни о чем не говорит. (Тем более что у вас краш был. Может как раз из-за этого.) Проверьте размер вектора.

Comment: перед "//set textures" я добавил строчку кода, но все равно не работает. ПОЧЕМУ??

Comment: На той же строке или на `worldSpriteLevelOne[h].push_back(sf::Sprite());`? Если `worldSpriteLevelOne` пустой, эта строчка выходит за границы вектора.

Comment: все, я исправил, проблема была в том что в worldSpriteLevelOne не было векторов :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотите  работать с вектором фиксированного размера. Тогда нужно  сразу  хранить вектора такого размера. Тогда вам не нужно хранить размеры, потому что сами вектора хранят эти размеры, и вам лишь нужно получать их:

```
class World : public sf::Transformable, public sf::Drawable
{
public:
    //...
    void generateWorld();
private:
    sf::Texture textureTile;
    //вектор для 10 строк с  20 _ тью пробелами
    std::vector<std::string> worldLevelOne =
        std::vector(10, std::string(" ", 20));
    //вектор для 10 векторов, содержащихся 20 sf::Sprite()
    std::vector<std::vector<sf::Sprite>> worldSpriteLevelOne =
        std::vector(10, std::vector<sf::Sprite>(20)) ;
};
```

Теперь функция член может быть написан проще и без ошибок:

```
void World::generateWorld()
{
    std::cout << "test1\n";
    //вам же нужно только одну строку заполнить символом '='
    worldLevelOne[6] = std::string("=", 20);
    //теперь получаем размеры векторов
    size_t height = worldSpriteLevelOne.size(),
        width = worldSpriteLevelOne[0].size();

    //и можете работать с элементами по своему усмотрению:
    for (_usi h = 0; h < height; ++h)
    {
        for (_usi w = 0; w < width; ++w)
        {
            //тут не нужно инициализировать вектор
            //set textures
            if (worldLevelOne[h][w] != ' ')
            {
                //ваш код
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**И в дополнении:**

Подумайте, не стоит ли вместо векторов использовать `std::array`, раз они не меняют свой размер?...

Comment: я это знал, но мне это не очень подходит

Comment: а std::array это же просто статический массив да?

Comment: Это стандартный  контейнер, который инкапсулирует массивы фиксированного размера. К тому же эффективнее по времени выполнения и памяти

Comment: а ограничения на них нету?

Comment: По моему вам стоит поискать статью или википедию или читать документацию про этого контейнера. Часто удобно  их использовать.  Не знаю  ограничения по какому критерию вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: ограничение по обьему

Comment: lofectr, ровно столько же, сколько можно выделить для обычного массива:

Comment: это мало.......